# I am trying to read a url from an xml file using c# using below

Tags: c#, xml-parsing

c# code to read the url value is

```cs
XmlDocument doc= new XmlDocument();
doc.Load("D:\\path to xml file.xml);

XmlNode node= doc.SelectSingleNode("tag1/tag2);

String name1 = node.Attribute["url"].Value;

return name1;
```

here not getting url value.

This is a sample XML

```xml
<tag1> 
    <tag2 type= "abc" url= "www.google.com"><tag2> 
</tag1>
```

Comment: Post a sample of the XML file so we can check for the nodes. Also, please someone edit this question.

Comment: Sure there is a url under 'tag1/tag2' node?

Comment: i was entering the xml file , but its not showing here not sure.
<tag1>

<tag2 type= "abc" url= "www.google.com">< tag2>
</tag1>

Comment: I would just `string name1 = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("tag2").Attributes["url"].Value;`

Comment: Despite the typo in the path (missing `"`) you have a second typo the XmlNode attributes collection name is not `Attribute` but `Attributes`

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you have wrong formatted xml. You dont't have a closing tag for tag2.

The right value is:

```xml
<tag1> 
 <tag2 type= "abc" url= "www.google.com"></tag2> 
</tag1>
```

Next, you have a typo (lost `s` letter )into `node.Attribute["url"].Value;`, the right code is `node.Attributes["url"].Value;`

```
    XmlDocument doc= new XmlDocument();
    doc.LoadXml("<tag1> \n    <tag2 type= \"abc\" url= \"www.google.com\"></tag2> \n</tag1>\n");
    
    
    XmlNode node= doc.SelectSingleNode("tag1/tag2");
    
    String name1 = node.Attributes["url"].Value;
```

Comment: doc.LoadXml(" here i should give the path of file right");

Comment: if not please suggest me how to provide the path

Comment: doc.Load("filename_here.xml"); instead of doc.LoadXml(...)